# finding time of the file received in a directory on reading a filename

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I read a file which have all the file names line by line which ($var) returns the file names in the directory `/home/mydir` .

```
input="/home/mydir/test/myfile"
while IFS= read -r var
do
/home/mydir/"$var"
done < "$input"
```

Now i want to find whether the file is in that directory for more than 5 hours in a if loop.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, thanks to comment by yeti:

edit again, oops, need input:

```
filetime=$(stat -c "%Z" "$input")
now=$(date "+%s")

age=$(($now - $filetime))

if (($age >= 18000)); then
   echo "File is OLD"
else
   echo "File is NEW"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks TiberiusKirk. I like to use ctime to find the time of the file. can you help me with that?

Comment: That's a job for `stat(1)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ctime". Do you mean the C function or the parameter of the "find" utility.  The $filetime in the script above is the last modification time of the file.

Comment: yes like modification time , I need to use change time . We have three types of time right access time, modification time and change time. For finding the time of the file i used 'find . -cmin -240' to get the files having change time greater than 4 hours. but don't know how to check for a particular file by specifying it's file name

Comment: Thanks to comment by yeti, I edited the answer to suit your needs.